# ChartJS Javascript - How to draw stacked bar histogram but with unknown size of dataset

Tags: javascript, plot, chart.js, histogram

I would like to draw a stacked bar histogram with ChartJS.
I saw lots of code and I know in general how to do it.

In my case the problem is the following :

I have, let's say, 30 dates that correspond to labels (or axis).

Then for each date, I may have one or multiple values that show specific data.

For example : Date 1 --> [1, 2], Date 2 --> [0.5], Date 3 --> [2, 4, 6, 8] etc.

How to do t knowing that the size of the dataset will vary.

So far, I did something like this :

```
  var chartdata = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: []
    }, {
      data: []
    }]
  };
  var canva_id = "#" + canvaID
  var ctx = $(canva_id);

  var options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 1
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Nb height'
        },

      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: ''
    }
  }
  var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartdata,
    options: options
  });

 [...]

var color = Array("#6ec72e", "#A77A2F", "#BF1515", "#4C4CAD", "#993366", "#401010");
  //Dict contain the date as a key and the array of data value as a value
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)) {

    chartInstance.data.labels[key] = value["date"];
    chartInstance.update();

    var count = 0;
    // create a new dataset with empty values
    var newDataset = {
      data: []
    };
    chartInstance.data.datasets.push(newDataset);

    for (let v = 0; v < value["height"].length; v++) {
      chartInstance.data.datasets[key].backgroundColor = color[v];

      chartInstance.data.datasets[key].data[v] = value["height"][v];

    }

    // Finally, make sure you update your chart, to get the result
    chartInstance.update();

  }
```

Any help on this please ?

Thank